# git push: Push all commits except the last one

Tags: git, push

Is there a way to push all my local commits to the remote repository *except the most recent one*? I'd like to keep the last one locally just in case I need to do an amend.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try this (assuming you're working with `master` branch and your remote is called `origin`):

```
git push origin HEAD^:master
```

`HEAD^` points to the commit before the last one in the current branch (the last commit can be referred as `HEAD`) so this command pushes this commit (with all previous commits) to remote `origin/master` branch.

In case you're interested you can find more information about specifying revisions in [this man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrevisions.html).

**Update:** I doubt that's the case, but anyway, you should be careful with that command if your last commit is merge. With merge commit in the `HEAD` `HEAD^` refers to the first parent of that commit, `HEAD^2` - to its second parent, etc.

Comment: If you're on Windows, make use you quote the `^` by doubling it up or you'll wind up pushing everything: `git push origin HEAD^^:master`

Comment: I got `zsh: no matches found: HEAD^:master`. If you use zsh (or have EXTENDED_GLOB enabled), you need to escape the caret: `\^`

Comment: Do I need to mention my local branch and remote if I want to push the current branch to the setup remote? Or could I just `git push HEAD^`?

Answer (score 57):

A more general approach that works to `push` up to a certain commit, is to specify the commit hash.

```
git push <remote> <commit hash>:<branch>
```

For example, if you have these commits:
`111111`  **<-- first commit**
`222222`
`333333`
`444444`
`555555`
`666666`  **<-- last commit**

```
git push origin 555555:master
```

..Will push all but your last commit to your remote `master` branch, and

```
git push origin 333333:myOtherBranch
```

..Will push commits up to and including `333333` to your remote branch `myOtherBranch`

Comment: error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,
starting with "refs/"). We tried to guess what you meant by

Answer (score 16):

Another possibility is to

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

to uncommit your most recent commit and move the changes to staged. Then you can

```
git push
```

and it will only push the remaining commits. This way you can see what will be pushed (via `git log`) before pushing.

Comment: You'll lose the commit message (of the latest, unpushed commit) though